# Why does Paul Blart yell "Hefeweizen" (english wheat beer) in Mall Cop?

Tags: plot-explanation, paul-blart-mall-cop

In the movie [Paul Blart: Mall Cop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Blart:_Mall_Cop) – I think part 2 – there's a scene where Kevin James is chased by a bird. He then yells "Hefewizen" to scare away the animal:

> Get away from me. Hefeweizen!

The first time I thought I misheard and then turned on subtitles that confirmed the line.

[image]

As [Hefeweizen (wheat beer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_beer) is a popular German type of beer I doubled up with laughter.

But does anyone know, why he used that term? is this a commonly used word in US language usage?

Comment: Because it is a funny word?

Comment: @BCdotWEB Probably. :D